# XCGLogger - How to set the Log Levels for All Logs

Tags: debugging, logging, xcglogger

I am using XCGLogger in my project, how to set the log level for all. I want to log all the logs like (debug, info,error,severe,verbose etc.,), for this how can i set the log level.

Answer (score 1):

Set the level to `.verbose`.

XCGLogger will only print messages with a log level that is greater to or equal to it's current log level setting. So a logger with a level of `.error` will only output log messages with a level of `.error`, or `.severe`. And so, a logger with a level of `.verbose` will show all log messages.

Comment: Thanks dave, yup got it.

Comment: @user842416 please don't forget to up vote and mark the answer as correct.